# 'list' object is not callable" while trying to convert filter into list

Tags: python, filter

I trying to use a filter () to find a list of words that start with 'w' and wrote the
[following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdsCE.jpg)

My code in text

list_1 = ['who', 'with', 'who', 'with', 'who', 'walks', 'when', 'world', 'walks']

#w = list_1[0][0]

w_list = list(filter(lambda w: w[0][0].lower() == 'w', list_1))

print(w_list)
len(w_list)

Could someone help to explain what went wrong with my code?

Thank you !

Comment: Please paste the code as text so we can copy and experiment.

Comment: It looks like you've assigned a list to a variable called "list" above what we see. Terminate your session to get rid of that assignment and try your example again. You could also just enter `list` to see what's in it. It should print `<class 'list'>` but will likely print some assigned list.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
scores = ['who', 'with', 'walks', 'does', 'sample']

filtered = filter(lambda word: word.startswith('w'), scores)

print(list(filtered))
```

The key point is, sometimes it's good to separate the lines of code from each other and see what is exactly failing. I can see your code is very similar to the above example that works (and don't just trust the colors, always inspect what a certain keyword actually is).

```
list = [] # This will make the code fail when calling print!

scores = ['who', 'with', 'walks', 'does', 'sample']
filtered = filter(lambda word: word.startswith('w'), scores)

print(list(filtered))
```

Output:

```
    print(list(filtered))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

The second code fails, because list is now not what `list` keyword refers to, instead, it's instantiated as a variable.

As others have commented, restart your current session (which will wipe out all the previously assigned variables in the current session), and run the code again. (Remember to not use keywords as variable names in Python)

Comment: To consider "W" : word.lower().startswith('w')

Comment: Hi Rikki, i have tried to use your suggested script for scores and got the same type error. I have also restarted my current session and still encountered the same

Comment: Hi Rikki, I copied the script and ran the session in a new workbook. It is working now.